# Matching digits using perl style regex

Tags: regex, perl

In one book(Speach and language processing I find out that regex - `/[0-9]*/` do not match any digit, the right regex for this - /[0-9][0-9]*/. Can somebody explain me why?

Comment: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#quantifiers

Comment: @mpapec thanks, cool source to learn regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The asterisk means "*zero or more*". For the zero case, `[0-9]*` matches an empty string. Instead of `[0-9][0-9]*`, you can also use `[0-9]+`, because `+` means "*one or more*".